# Solving a puzzle using swi-prolog

Tags: prolog

I've been given as an assignment to write using prolog a solver for 
the battleships solitaire puzzle. To those unfamiliar, the puzzle deals
with a 6 by 6 grid on which a series of ships are placed according to the provided 
constraints on each row and column, i.e. the first row must contain 3 squares with ships, the second row must contain 1 square with a ship, the third row must contain 0 squares etc for the other rows and columns.

Each puzzle comes with it's own set of constraints and revealed squares, typically two. An example can be seen here:
[battleships](http://www.brainbashers.com/battleships.asp)

So, here's what I've done:

```
step([ShipCount,Rows,Cols,Tiles],[ShipCount2,Rows2,Cols2,Tiles2]):-
   ShipCount2 is ShipCount+1,
   nth1(X,Cols,X1),
   X1\==0,
   nth1(Y,Rows,Y1),
   Y1\==0,
   not(member([X,Y,_],Tiles)),
       pairs(Tiles,TilesXY),
   notdiaglist(X,Y,TilesXY),
   member(T,[1,2,3,4,5,6]),
   append([X,Y],[T],Tile),
   append([Tile],Tiles,Tiles2),
   dec_elem1(X,Cols,Cols2),dec_elem1(Y,Rows,Rows2).


dec_elem1(1,[A|Tail],[B|Tail]):- B is A-1.
dec_elem1(Count,[A|Tail],[A|Tail2]):- Count1 is Count-1,dec_elem1(Count1,Tail,Tail2).

neib(X1,Y1,X2,Y2) :- X2 is X1,(Y2 is Y1 -1;Y2 is Y1+1; Y2 is Y1).
neib(X1,Y1,X2,Y2) :- X2 is X1-1,(Y2 is Y1 -1;Y2 is Y1+1; Y2 is Y1).
neib(X1,Y1,X2,Y2) :- X2 is X1+1,(Y2 is Y1 -1;Y2 is Y1+1; Y2 is Y1).

notdiag(X1,Y1,X2,Y2) :- not(neib(X1,Y1,X2,Y2)).
notdiag(X1,Y1,X2,Y2) :- neib(X1,Y1,X2,Y2),((X1 == X2,t(Y1,Y2));(Y1 == Y2,t(X1,X2))). 
notdiaglist(X1,Y1,[]).
notdiaglist(X1,Y1,[[X2,Y2]|Tail]):-notdiag(X1,Y1,X2,Y2),notdiaglist(X1,Y1,Tail).

t(X1,X2):- X is abs(X1-X2), X==1.

pairs([],[]).
pairs([[X,Y,Z]|Tail],[[X,Y]|Tail2]):-pairs(Tail,Tail2).
```

I represent a state with a list: `[Count,Rows,Columns,Tiles]`. The last state must be
`[10,[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0], somelist]`. A puzzle starts from an initial state, for example

```
initial([1, [1,3,1,1,1,2] , [0,2,2,0,0,5] , [[4,4,1],[2,1,0]]]).
```

I try to find a solution in the following manner:

```
run:-initial(S),step(S,S1),step(S1,S2),....,step(S8,F).
```

Now, here's the difficulty: if i restrict myself to one type of ship parts by using  `member(T,[1])`

instead of

```
member(T,[1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

it works fine. However, when I use the full range of possible values for T which are needed
later, the query never ends since it runs for too long. this puzzles me, since :

- (a) it works for 6 types of ships but only for 8 steps instead of 9
- (b) going from a single type of ship to 6 types increases the number
  of options for     just the last step by a factor of 6, which
  shouldn't have such a dramatic effect.

  So, what's going on?

---

Comment: The head of the last clause in `notdiaglist` should probably be `notdiaglist(X1, Y1, [[X2, Y2, _] | Tail])`, no? `step` fails very quickly otherwise.

I'm also getting a failure for nine iterations of `step` no matter what options for T there are. It takes a long time (48s) *and* it fails.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.
1. the last clause in notdiaglist should not be x2,y2,_ because the list it expects is a list of 2d-points. I use two list types: 2d points and "3d" points - 2d coordinates + ship type

2. strange that you're getting a failure. my query doesn't end at all. what version of swi-prolog do you use?

Comment: EDIT: I've changed the code a bit because you're right- I doesn't work as is. I've added a a predicate "pairs" to convert from "3d" points to 2d points. I apologize, I wasn't careful when pasting from the editor.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly, what's going on is that Prolog is trying to sift through an enormous space of possibilities.

You're correct that altering that line increases the search space of the *last* call by a factor of six, note that the size of the search space of, say, nine calls, isn't proportional to 9 times the size of one call. Prolog will backtrack on failure, so it's proportional (bounded above, actually) to the size of the possible results of one call *raised to the ninth power*.

That means we can expect the size of the space Prolog needs to search to grow by at most a factor of 6^9 = 10077696 when we allow `T` to take on 6 times as many values.

---

Of course, it doesn't help that (as far as I was able to tell) a solution doesn't exist if we call `step` 9 times starting with `initial` anyways. Since that last call is going to fail, Prolog will keep trying until it's exhausted all possibilities (of which there are a great many) before it finally gives up.

---

As far as a solution goes, I'm not sure I know enough about the problem. If the value if T is the kind of ship that fits in the grid (e.g. single square, half of a 2-square-ship, part of a 3-square-ship) you should note that that gives you a lot more information than the numbers on the rows/columns.

Right now, in pseudocode, your `step` looks like this:

- Find a (X,Y) pair that has non-zero markings on its row/column
- Check that there isn't already a ship there
- Check that it isn't diagonal to a ship
- Pick a kind of ship-part for it to be.

I'd suggest you approach like this:

- Finish any already placed ship-bits to form complete ships (if we can't: fail)
- Until we're finished:

  - Find acceptable places to place ship
  - Check that the markings on the row/column aren't zero
  - Try to place an *entire* ship here. (instead of a single part)

By using the most specific information that we have first (in this case, the previously placed parts), we can reduce the amount of work Prolog has to do and make things return reasonably fast.

Comment: Thank you for answering, qu4ntumcpa. 
First of all, I've made a small edit adding a "pairs" predicate to convert between "3d" points and 2d points because otherwise step fails immediately. Sorry about that, I was trying to paste cleaner code, turns out I cut too much.

anyway, it obviously still doesn't work. You're correct in that the search space is 6 ^ 9. what's not clear is why prolog is able to return quickly for 8 steps, that is , for a search space of 6 ^ 8 but not for 6 ^ 9?

Comment: as for your idea, the truth is that the improvement in search space wouldn't be that great because every ship, except for the shortest of  length 1, has a vertical and a horizontal possible orientation which complicates matters somewhat.

Comment: It returns quickly for the 8-step case because it finds a solution without significant backtracking--so it runs in close to linear time. Since the 9th step has no solution, it must backtrack through the entire space.